# Flutter, help on design a clickable shape with clickable icons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter!
I need to realize the following shape as shown in the figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nxJD.jpg), rounded by blue rectangle. I made it easy on Xcode and Android Studio but I've some issues to make it on Flutter.

It is pretty simple ... it is a square with a quadrangle under an image, below an html text coming from the backend. The big Icons.share as well as the Icons.mail_outline, and Icons.favorite has to be clickable and generates actions. I can also obtain the result with a clickability on left and right parts of the shape, except the quadrangle, rhombus.

After two days of testing Container, Stack, Padding, Path, ... still I've not reached an acceptable result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done the layout for you here the result
[image]

And here is the code

```
SizedBox(
        height: 80,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                height: 50,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    const Spacer(flex: 1,),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Text('Ti piace?'),
                        IconButton(icon: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.heart),
                        onPressed: (){
                          //do what you want
                        },),
                        const Text('0'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Spacer(flex: 2,),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        const Text('0'),
                        IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.mail_outline),
                        onPressed: (){
                          //do what you want
                        },),
                        const Text('Contattami'),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const Spacer(flex: 1,),
                  ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: RotationTransition(
                turns: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(45 / 360),
                child: Container(
                  height: 45,
                    width: 45,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey,spreadRadius: 2,blurRadius: 5),
                      ]
                    ),
                    child: RotationTransition(
                        turns: const AlwaysStoppedAnimation(-45 / 360),
                        child: IconButton(onPressed: (){}, icon: const Icon(Icons.share)))),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thank you Kaleb. 
The shape appears in the middle of the image ... my body: code
Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipRRect(
                  ... image
                ),
                SizedBox( ... your code ... ),
                SafeArea( ... text),
If I remove the top Stack the shape appears on the bottom wit no overlay on the image :-(